# Bug Village iPad game auto notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, app-store

Don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but I will take my chances.

There is an iOS game called Bug Village that will from time to time automatically pops up an alert about the character in that game needed feeding.... etc. even though the game was not currently active.

Question:  What technique or how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you're talking about exactly but outside the app, it must be [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

From what you're telling they either use `UILocalNotification` or `Push Notifications`. But Local notifications sounds best for this task.

Read the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get started